# Entity Beans doesn't permit to define Map<String, Object> property

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying add a Map property,

```
Map<String, Object> map;
```

to an Entity Bean.

I am getting error "Basic Attributes can only be of the following Java Primitive Types, Wrapper Primitive Types...".

Any Reason!

Comment: Can you share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map a collection in JPA without any annotations. You need to point explicit what's the relation between your entity and objects inside your collection.

Have a look at Oracle JPA tutorial.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html

Especially at *Using Collections in Entity Fields and Properties* section.

Comment: An Example for Map in an Entity bean, please!

Comment: If your Object is a java.lang.Object, not an another entity, you should use @ElementCollection annotation.